# How to manually adjust symbol positioning in `\underset`?

Tags: math-mode

I have the following:

`\underset{{}^u}{\sim}`

which looks like the left; I would like it to look more like the right image.

[image]

The changes were shrinking the "u", bringing it closer to the tilde, and raising the whole thing so it doesn't hang below the line. I tried using a `\raisebox` but had no success.

Comment: `\raisebox` apparently works only in text mode (and not in math mode).  A soft hack could bypass this limitation by first creating a text environment with the `\text{...}` command from `amsmath`, and implement `raisbox` inside it-- of course again surrounding the math symbol to be `underset` within `$`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange.

### Edit # 2

To raise the whole operator, could use `\scalebox` from the `graphics` package.  This translates better, as is found independent of the font size option of the `documentclass` (the original version doesn't scale equally well to a `10pt` or `11pt` document)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphics}
\newcommand{\upperset}[2]{\:
  \underset{
            \text{\raisebox{1.2ex}{\smash{\scalebox{0.8}{$#1$}}}}%
           }
           {
            \text{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\smash{$#2$}}}
           }
                       \:}
\begin{document}
    $x \underset{{}^u}{\sim} y$ \quad\phantom{\strut}
    $x \upperset{{}^u}{\sim} y$
\end{document}
```

giving very near to what you wanted:

[image]

### Original post

Maybe this could be a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\upperset}[2]{%
    \underset{%
        \text{\raisebox{1ex}{\smash{\fontsize{5}{5}$#1$}}}
              }{#2}%
                         }
\begin{document}
    $x \underset{{}^u}{\sim} y$ \quad\phantom{\strut}
    $x \upperset{{}^u}{\sim} y$
\end{document}
```

which gives this:

[image]

Comment: 2nd edit is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants the underset to sit on the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\newcommand\runderset[2][\sim]{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-.2pt}{\scriptscriptstyle#2}{#1}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
$a\runderset{x}b$

$a\runderset[=]y b$
\end{document}
```

[image]